# Field-key have different value in response from api

Tags: java, rest, jackson, rest-assured

I have a problem with returned value from API response. I have model:

```
public class MfConfig {

public List<Multiplications> multiplications;}
```

I run test via REST ASSURED with Jackson. Test return response, In response I have many objects. In these objects I have one field (key) returned few times. And when returned value for field is empty, field is an array, but when field has value, field is an object:

```
  "multiplications": [
        
  ]

  "multiplications": {
    "id": 133389
  }
```

When I have model like above, I got:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["multiplications"] is not a JSONObject.
```

When I change model to:

```
public class MfConfig {

public Multiplications multiplications;}
```

I got:

```java
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type 'test.Multiplications` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
```

In test I use:

```java
given(requestSpecification)
.baseUri(endpoint)
.when()
.get()
.then()
.extract()
.as((Multiplication.class)
```

I can change i to:

```java
given(requestSpecification)
.baseUri(endpoint)
.when()
.get()
.then()
.extract()
.as((Multiplication[].class)
```

But I got error for response with Object. And vice versa. In model I ve tried something like:

```
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
public Multiplications multiplications;
```

or

```
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
public List<Multiplications> multiplications;
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe someone have idea for response, where one field has different type like object and array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setting POJO

```
@Data
public class MfConfig {
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    public List<Multiplications> multiplications;
}

@Data
public class Multiplications {
    public int id;
}
```

2. Deserialization

```
MfConfig mfConfig = given(requestSpecification)
    .baseUri(endpoint)
    .when()
    .get()
    .then()
    .extract()
    .as(MfConfig.class)
```

3. Result

```
MfConfig(multiplications=[])

MfConfig(multiplications=[Multiplications(id=133389)])
```