# Please provide the code to create payload for the below Json in restassured using TestNG Java

Tags: rest-assured

```json
{
    "employerId":"{{employerId}}",
    "firstName":"Sarah",
    "lastName": "Longfield",
    "last4TIN":"7066",
    "emailId": "deepakre+356441@gmail.com.com",
    "cellPhone": "+912637489264",
    "callbackURLs":{
        "identityCallbackUrls":[
            "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7998c7f8a"
        ],
        "notificationUrls":[
            "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7998c7f8a"
        ]
    },
    "addressLine1":"250 Vesey Street",
    "addressLine2":"",
    "zip":"10281",
    "city":"New York",
    "state":"NY",
    "dateOfBirth":"09-12-1995"  
}
```

I have written 3 POJO classes but i am not getting the answer specifically i am focusing on below part

This is what is been excepted

```json
 "callbackURLs":{
        "identityCallbackUrls":[
            "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7998c7f8a"
        ],
        "notificationUrls":[
            "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7998c7f8a"
        ]
    },
```

When i tried this is what is i achieved

```json
"callbacks": [
        {
            "identitycallbackURL": "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7994c7f8a"
        },
        {
            "notificationURL": "https://webhook.site/4d0e80d0-ece1-4208-8f76-9ac7994c7f8a"
        }
    ],
```

I want two different array in one json object but i am getting two object in one array
Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Please provide your POJO.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand, few days ago I had the same problem. Here is solution -> [Field-key have different value in response from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206663/field-key-have-different-value-in-response-from-api)

You should use @JsonFormat Jackson annotation in model.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public class CallbackURLs {

public List<String> identityCallbackUrls;
public List<String> notificationUrls;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

public class Example {

public String employerId;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String last4TIN;
public String emailId;
public String cellPhone;
public CallbackURLs callbackURLs;
public String addressLine1;
public String addressLine2;
public String zip;
public String city;
public String state;
public String dateOfBirth;

}
```

I think this is the most important thing that you miss:

```
public List<String> identityCallbackUrls;
public List<String> notificationUrls;
```